# Reboot computer through WCF with WMI hosted on IIS c#

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, wmi, reboot

I have a WCF Service which is running on IIS. ApplicationPool uses the LocalSystem Identity.
The WCF Service has an method for rebooting the system with WMI using the following code:

```
        ManagementBaseObject mboShutdown = null;
        ManagementClass mcWin32 = null;
        try
        {
            mcWin32 = new ManagementClass("Win32_OperatingSystem");
            mcWin32.Get();

            // You can't shutdown without security privileges
            mcWin32.Scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;
            ManagementBaseObject mboShutdownParams = mcWin32.GetMethodParameters("Win32Shutdown");

            // Flag 6 means we want to trigger a force reboot
            mboShutdownParams["Flags"] = "6";
            mboShutdownParams["Reserved"] = "0";

            foreach (ManagementObject manObj in mcWin32.GetInstances())
            {
                mboShutdown = manObj.InvokeMethod("Win32Shutdown", mboShutdownParams, null);
                var result = Convert.ToInt32(mboShutdown["returnValue"]);
                if (result != 0) throw new Win32Exception(result, "Could not restart local machine!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SkippyLogger.WriteError(ex, "Error in IISAdminService.Restart");
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (mcWin32 != null)
                mcWin32.Dispose();
        }
```

The method throw an exception with "Privilege not held".

---

Comment: Is rebooting the only reason this web service was created for?

Comment: No. It's also setting the computer name

Comment: Do you NEED to use WMI to shut down the computer? Have you considered opening a Process and calling the shutdown program in windows 32?

Comment: If the naming is done via WMI too, all the code does not need to run on target machine. The WMI class system can operate remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to try...

- [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e4b8c701-90c7-4fb8-a38c-6b8ce4386cb7/wmi-privilege-not-held-error-when-attempting-to-remote-shutdown-a-machine?forum=netfxbcl)
- Can you run the same method, as LocalSystem outside of IIS - i.e host it as a windows service installed of IIS?
- We have a similar system (hosted as a windows service) and it performs the actual reboot using [this](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Content/ViewAssociatedFile.aspx?rzp=%2FKB%2Fsystem%2FStartButtonRenamer%2FArticle_src.zip&zep=start%20button%20renamer%2Fstart%20button%20rename%2FWindowsController.cs&obid=19021&obtid=2&ovid=1) class.

Comment: Yes i've tried the first thing, but same results.
Yes, outside from IIS it works fine. Also as Windows Service.